# How to configure port forwarding a public IP to private IP in Windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, networking, iis, port-forwarding, wide-area-network

I have an API hosted on IIS it can be visited simply by typing `192.168.1.200:82/api/suivi`.

I want to make it possible for internet users to use my public IP `41.180....:82/api/suivi` to get the response.

The key solution is to use **port forwarding** on the modem/router, but I still can't make this work.

I have a D-link DSL-124, for an ADSL connection.
I added the port 82 to be forworded, and in the WAN setting option I used IP address instead of interface, and put my public IP.

In the service name section I used the name of my site `myapp` instead of the usual types `AUTH,DNS,FTP,IPSEC,POP3,PPTP,SMTP,SSH,TELNET,TFTP,WEB` as shown here: [image].

What is missing or wrong here in this configuration?

Thank you

**EDIT**

There are no exception in the logs, i.e, the problem is in the configuration

Answer (score 1):

In WAN Settings, instead of using IP Address choose Interface option. Now in WAN interfaces section enter interface on which your WAN cable is connected.

As refered in datasheet at https://www.dlinkmea.com/upload/downloadable/DSL_124_I1_Manual_v1_00_DI__5a81627bd9c87.pdf on page number 75.

Comment: Thank you  for your effort, that still does not work though.